# QTreeWidget ширина колонки с item widget

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть QTreeWidget с двумя колонками. В первой - текст, а во второй - QPushButton. Не получается задать размеры кнопки, а так же задать размеры второго столбца. При попытке задать размер столбца по контенту, второй столбец вообще исчезает. Как изменить ширину второго столбца?

```
tree_widget_->setColumnCount(2);
tree_widget_->header()->resizeSection(1, 10);
tree_widget_->header()->setStretchLastSection(false);
tree_widget_->header()->setResizeMode(0,QHeaderView::Stretch);
tree_widget_->topLevelItem(4)->addChild( wiop = new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList() << QString( "Расстояние: %1 км" ).arg( range ) ) );
tree_widget_->setItemWidget(tree_widget_->topLevelItem(4)->child(0),1,range_plot_button_ = new QPushButton("График",tree_widget_));
range_plot_button_->resize(10,10);
```

Answer (score 3):

Я сделала следующее  `tree_widget_->header()->setResizeMode(1,QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);` 
и после этого ширина колонки изменилась. 
Хотя до этого я пыталась сделать так `tree_widget_->resizeColumnToContents(1);` но не получала никаких результатов.